# JSF 2.1 Validation of two inputs at the same time using Ajax

Tags: java, jsf-2, validation, customvalidator

I have a problem with validation of two inputs at the same time.

In my validator I need data from both:

1. `<h:selectOneListbox>`
2. `<h:inputText>`

The idea is to check if an address is reachable for delivery personnel.
During validation I make a request to DB. And look for a combination of streetName + houseNumber.

#### Here is a part of my JSF page.

```
    <h:form>
        <p> 
            <h:outputLabel for="streetsList" value="Street"/>
            <h:selectOneListbox id="streetsList" binding="#{theStreetsList}" 
                                size="1" value="#{makeOrder.streetName}" required="true">
                <f:selectItems value="#{locationView.streetNames}" var="streetName" 
                               itemLabel="#{streetName}" itemValue="#{streetName}"/>
            </h:selectOneListbox>
        </p>

        <p class="address_details">
            <h:outputLabel for="houseInput" value="#{msgs.house}"/>
            <h:inputText id="houseInput" class="tab_input house_input" 
                         value="#{makeOrder.house}" required="true">
                <f:validator validatorId="AddressValidator" />
                <f:attribute name="street" value="#{theStreetsList}" />
                <f:ajax event="blur" execute="streetsList houseInput" render="m_houseInput" />
            </h:inputText>
            <h:message id="m_houseInput" for="houseInput" style="color:red" />

            <h:outputLabel for="flatInput" class="flat_label" value="#{msgs.flat}"/>
            <h:inputText class="tab_input flat_input" value="#{makeOrder.flat}"/>
        </p>
    </h:form>
```

#### Here is validate method of my class:

```
@Override
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) 
        throws ValidatorException {

    String house = (String) value;

    UIInput streetsComponent = (UIInput) component.getAttributes().get("street");
    String streetName = (String) streetsComponent.getSubmittedValue();

    Street orderStreet = this.findStreetInDB(streetName, house);

    if (orderStreet.getName().equals("dummyStreet")) {

        // Show error
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(
                "Unfortunately we do not deliver to this address, yet.");
        msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        throw new ValidatorException(msg);
    }
}
```

My problem is that `String streetName` is `null`.

**P.S.** Values of this element are rendered fine. And I even can submit a form if I don't use validation.

- What am I doing wrong?
- What is the right way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to point out which variable in your code is `null`. Is it `streetsComponent`? Or do you already not understand what a [`NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) is? This problem falls then beyond JSF to basic Java.

Comment: I don't get any output from GlassFish for some strange reason. Usually it works =) But when I submit a form in "ordinary" way, then problem appears at this line: `String streetName = (String) streetsComponent.getSubmittedValue();` And I can see a Stack Trace in browser. http://prntscr.com/ucx3y

Comment: So.. Your concrete problem is that you don't understand why `streetsComponent` is `null`? Have you looked closer at the attribute name if it matches the one as declared in `<f:attribute>`?

Comment: OMG! Just noticed. Sorry for my inadvertence. But I'm still getting the same error. Now I'll update code in question.

Comment: Do you really still get a NPE? What variable exactly is `null`? At first sight, the new code wouldn't cause a NPE at all, but a `ClassCastException` because `#{theStreetsList.submittedValue}` does not return an `UIInput`, but a `String`.

Comment: Thanks, so attribute should look like this to return UIInput:
`<f:attribute name="street" value="#{theStreetsList}" />`
Still NPE. I'll try to reboot, maybe than Glassfish will show some stack trace output.

Comment: You keep forgotting to tell which variable exactly is `null`. Please always point it out instead of generically telling "I got NPE" as if you have no clue what exactly causes a NPE. Accessing a `null` variable using the period operator `.` causes a NPE. It's Java 101 to figure which variable exactly it is. You should not tell "I got NPE", but "variable `x` is `null`". It's nothing more than obvious that accessing it would cause NPE. Thus, is it still `streetsComponent` which is `null`?

Comment: It is not about forgetting. I just don't get any error messages from GlassFish in Netbeans. (Only for this error). As I can see from message in browser a problem is still with `streetsComponent` variable. Which is `null`.

Comment: Running a debugger so that you can just explore the variables in the heap, or adding a logger or poor man's `System.out.println()` statements printing the variables of interest before they're being accessed would be little effort resulting in very valuable information which helps us to solve your problem. Okay, so you're absolutely positive that `streetsComponent` is `null`? Well, that's impossible based on the code and information provided so far. Perhaps you're not running the code you think you're running (clean/rebuild/etc), or you still misidentified the actual variable which is `null`.

Comment: I do appreciate a lot your help. I'll post new data as soon as I'll get it.

Comment: Cleaned, debugged. Copied method from my question to my project. As you said - my variable `streetsComponent` is not null anymore. `String streetName` which represents the submitted value is null now. I'll try to figure out why it happens. Thanks, BalusC.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25233/discussion-between-xmapact-and-balusc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *String streetName which represents the submitted value is null now.*

Components are processed in the order they appear in the component tree. During processing, the submitted value is obtained, converted and validated. If anything went successfully, then the converted/validated value is set as component's value and the submitted value is set to `null`.

In case of a validator on 2 components, obtaining the submitted value of another component works only if the validatior is invoked on the 1st component. But in your case it's invoked on the 2nd component and you should be using `UIInput#getValue()` instead of `getSubmittedValue()`. Note that this returns the converted and validated value and thus not the "raw" submitted value.